# Retrieve ship to address if different than buyer address in notify_url

Tags: php, paypal

Does PayPal send the **ship to** address back to the *notify_url* when it is different from the buyer's address in their PayPal account?

If so, what are the variable names of the ship to address, so I can retrieve them?

By the way, I am not sending a "no_shipping" variable, so the default is used - prompt for shipping address, but do not require one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever address is included with the transaction then it will be returned in the IPN.  PayPal's IPN variables list displays the fields you should expect under the [Buyer Information section](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB01I0Y4).

Comment: Looking at the Buyer Information section, I find: address_street, defined as "Customer's street address". This would be the address of the buyer as entered in their PayPal account. I'm looking for the ship to address that the buyer enters (when it is different than their own address). I don't find a variable defined as the ship to address on the Buyer Information page you linked to above.